# Javascript Statistics Calculator

Tags: javascript, statistics

I am trying to make a JS function that takes in: 
- Count of entries
- Minimum of entries
- Maximum of entries
- Range of entries
- Sum of entries
- Average of entries

I am trying to use a loop alert to take in the user input but with no luck, here is my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function show_prompt() {
      i = 1;
      do {
        var number = prompt("Please Enter a Number");
        i++;
        if (number % 2) {
          document.write("Number: " + number);
          document.write("<br>");
        }
      }
      while (i <= 15);
    }
    show_prompt();
  </script>
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 55px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
    .tasks {
      color: white;
      font-size: 250%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

Many Thanks

James

Comment: What is the purpose of i<15?

Comment: i wasnt sure how else to stop it @user2181397

Answer (score 0):

I tried some codes. Try this snippet.https://jsfiddle.net/2fo8ctgv/2/

```
var i = 0,
    answer=true,
nums=[],
min,
max,
avrg = 0,
sum = 0;
do{
    var num;
    if(num=prompt('number')){
        nums.push(num)
      i++;
  } else {
  answer = false;
  }
} while(answer);
  nums.forEach(function(c){sum+=c;});
nums.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});

min = nums[0];
max = nums[nums.length-1];
avrg=sum/i;
console.log(min,max,avrg,sum);
```